# Neighborhood of zero on weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

I have a homework, I have tried so much on this question, but I couldn't solve it. How can I prove it? Can you help me? Thank you.

> $E$ is a normed space and $E'$ is the topological dual of $E$. If $\phi_1,...,\phi_n\in E'$ and $\epsilon>0$, then
>
> $U(0;\phi_1,...,\phi_n;\epsilon)$=$\{x\in E:|\phi_j(x)|<\epsilon,1\leq j\leq n\}$ which is neighborhood of $0$ on $(E',\sigma(E',E))$ weak topology, includes a following neighborhood:
>
> $U(0;\psi_1,...,\psi_n;\delta)$=$\{x\in E:|\psi_j(x)|<\delta, \psi_1,...,\psi_n\in E' ~~~\textrm{linear independent}~~~\delta>0,1\leq j\leq n\}$

Comment: What have you tried exactly?

Comment: By using $\phi_n$ functions, I tried to get linear independent functions. I don't have so much information on weak topology. I have researched many articles on the Internet, but couldn't get the appropriate information about my question.